# If I build a web application in ASP.NET, am I married to Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Doesn't Visual Studio generate all kinds of things when you build asp.net websites?  I haven't used it in a while but back in webforms with a the dal and a bll, VS generated xml files and other things (don't remember what).  And, while I technically could use notepad to fix it, VS seemed to be the only way to make sure things worked right.

How about today with MVC or something else asp.net?  Am I tied to Visual Studio forever if I want to build websites?  I liked in PHP that I can open up a file and it be simple to change things and it just works.

I am *not* knocking Visual Studio.  It is a great product, but for those in my group that do not use it, it is a learning curve.  Not asking for why asp.net is better than php or vice versa, just about visual studio.

EDIT:  Is Visual Studio the BEST way to build asp.net projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), [Webmatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express) but i suggest [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx), its open source.

> sharpDevelop (short for SharpDevelop) is a free IDE for C#, VB.NET and Boo projects on Microsoft's .NET platform. It is open-source, and you can download both sourcecode and executables from this site. In addition, you can find the latest information and changes on #develop, as well as get in touch with the team in the forum.

#### More Information

- [SharpDevelop Website](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx)
- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
- [Webmatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)
- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can build with MSBuild from command line, just simple msbuild.exe app.sln

Comment: that seems pretty extreme...like notepad.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: sorry, somehow I understud that you don't wont to use an IDE at all

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MonoDevelop, which will run on Windows/Mac/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), which is free and aims to simplify the web development process. Another alternative is [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), which is an open source IDE for multiple platforms.